# Two (not main) thread synchronisation

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have two threads (A and B) + one main thread (C) running. Thread A contains an object that is used for writing to the database. Sometimes Thread B also wants to write to the database.

As I understood for this reason I must create synchronization between thread A and B. If I use `Synchronize` method in thread B it will do synchronization with main thread C, but not with A. How to deal in this situation?

Comment: Use a serializing lock. On Windows that usually means a critical section object.

Comment: tried otl.17slon.com ? they have a view thread-to-thread sync primitives

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is best integrated into the shared service or resource so that both threads do not need to know of each other. Pseudocode:

```
uses
  SyncObj;
```

---

```
TSomeService = class
private
  FLock : TCriticalSection;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure UseService;
end;
```

---

```
constructor TSomeService.Create;
begin
FLock := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

destructor TSomeService.Destroy;
begin
FreeAndNil (FLock);
end;

procedure TSomeService.UseService;
begin
FLock.Enter;
try
  // ...
finally
  FLock.Leave;
 end;
```

This is completely transparent to both threads, so both threads can just call

```
FSomeService.UseService;
```

without bothering with synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use critical sections to prevent simultaneous access to memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of inter-thread comms to signal a message from B to A to write data to the DB. This keeps DB access to one thread.  Exact mechanism depends on how thread B normally gets its inputs, (how does it?).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to databases, most database components are not thread-safe unless you use database sessions.  It is usually better to give each thread its own connection to the database instead and not share connections or components across thread boundaries.